# In databases what's the difference between the words "row" and "record"?

Tags: row, rdbms, record

In databases what's the difference between the words "row" and "record"? Is it that a record contains multiple rows?

EDIT: are they *exactly* the same?

EDIT 2: The first sentence of chapter 14 of *Databases Systems The Complete Book* reads

> It is not sufficient simply to scatter the records that represent
>   tuples of a relation among various blocks.

Are you guys sure your sure that records and tuples mean the same thing?

Comment: Hi Celeritas! [**Here is a useful link for your question**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31805/what-is-the-difference-between-a-record-and-a-row-in-sql-server) , Although your question has been answered but I feel that I should post a link for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference philosophically. Again the taxonomy is not the same in every language, every database etc, so there is no one answer. But you can consider it this way

A data base has tables. Each table just like when you draw a table in Excel, has columns and rows. So we can say each table has rows.

But it is possible that data for a single type of entity is stored in multiple tables. For example, you can have Employee ID, First name, Last name in one table called Employee and that can be a row for each employee.

But it is also possible that additional information like address is stored elsewhere called Address.

So later when you query and get full details of the employee, you get employee details from Employee and address table. That can be considered a record or full record. It is made up of data from rows of multiple tables.

But again, there is no one answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although already answered very well; I would like to add my points too.

These words are used interchangeably.

```
 1          2         3              4 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Row    =  Record  =  Tuple        =  Entity 

Column =  Field   =  Attribute    =  Attribute

table  =  File    =  Relation     =  Entity Types(or Entity Set)
```

- 4 terminology good to use when we learns ER-Modules
- 3 use when Relational Model
- 2 in- general scene, `DataBase books start with these terminology` because these are much commonly used by people in real life, also in file-system.

**EDIT**:
`It is not sufficient simply to scatter the records that represent tuples of a relation among various blocks.`

`Record` is the basic unit in storage system that have implicit meaning. In DBMS the word `record` use in chapter describes how database tables stores on disk blocks. A sentence from [my book](http://web2.aabu.edu.jo/tool/course_file/lec_notes/901331_Fundamentals_of_Database_Systems,_6th_Edition_%280136086209%29.pdf) `primary methods of organizing files of records on disk`. In DBMS a `record-oriented filesystem` is a file system where files are stored as collections of records.      (`RECORD/Field/File/Block` are File-System (Operating System) Terminology) Bit command then row in storage system context. Although, `Records` is also called `tuples, structs, or compound data`.

---

I have not added terminologies use in OO-database design for some reasons. they are
{ object, data-type, OBJECT STRUCTURE or (STRUCTURE)}

---

Using correct terminology at correct place is good practice for technical person, specially if one is teaching!

Comment: -1 Actually incorrect. This answer is too narrow-minded and only thinks about the terms within the confines of (relational( databases - several other database types don't have "rows" but still have "records"

Comment: The whole answer is about relational databases. There are other types of database and the question does not specify "relational". Put a disclainer to the top of your question to that effect - since these days practically all databases in use are relational, it would then be a useful answer

Comment: Although this doesn't deserve for negative I feel. Its yours choice!

Comment: Read (Edited) previous comment - I'm removing the -1 and assuming you'll edit :)

Comment: @Bohemian: Thanks to remove `-1` In India its 1:30 AM night. I will improve my answer next day. Thanks Bohemian!

Answer (score 1):

In the *relational* database world, the terms can be used interchangeably.

There are other kinds of databases in which the terms do not appear; for instance, there are document databases, key-value stores, and graph databases.

But in the common relational database, a table (or relation) is made up of many rows (or records, or tuples), each representing an "object" of the "type" described by the table.  The difference in terms is really one of perception: use *row* when you are viewing the tables pictorially; use *record* when emphasizing physical structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, they are the same thing.

When I was taught (and I'll admit this was a while ago), it was just rows and columns, but you can equally use records in place of rows, and attributes in place of columns if you so wish.

I know that some people prefer to reserve row for a single table entry and use record for joined queries (from multiple tables for example) but I'm not sure that nomenclature is widespread.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of working with a database API, like ADO.NET then the two are largely synonymous. However less formally "record" tends to refer to a unit of logical information, such as a few denormalised rows combined (such as the details of a Purchase Order combined with the individual Line Items of the order).

Answer (score 0):

They are not *always* the same thing.

They mean the same thing in the realm of relational databases, but "record" has meaning outside relational databases.

For example, `IMS` databases had "records", and COBOL had the RECORD keyword, and COBOL was at one time the main language used for business and pre-dates relational database existence.

"row" is a strictly relational database term.